# Changing Local Security Values through Batch, running PowerShell wrapped with Secedit

Tags: powershell, batch-file, windows-10

I am using batch to edit Local Security Policy options, and I need to edit a lot of them. Currently, I use the following code to do so:

```
echo Do Not Display Last Username At Logon Screen Enabled
secedit.exe /export /cfg C:\secconfig.cfg
powershell -Command "(gc C:\secconfig.cfg) -replace 'DontDisplayLastUserName=4,0', 'DontDisplayLastUserName=4,1' | Out-File -encoding ASCII C:\secconfigupdated.cfg"
secedit.exe /configure /db %windir%\securitynew.sdb /cfg C:\secconfigupdated.cfg /areas SECURITYPOLICY
del c:\secconfig.cfg
del c:\secconfigupdated.cfg
```

This to my understanding creates .cfg files, edits them with PowerShell, and then applies the change to secedit, which in turn changes Local Security Policy. I have a limited understanding of how to work with the code above, and do not know what certain aspects are for, such as the '4' value when replacing  'DontDisplayLastUserName'. Knowing this would be helpful when working with the code.

Mainly, I need to know how/where to find the values for Local Security Policy, such as the value for the 'Do Not Display Last Username At Logon Screen' setting, is 'DontDisplayLastUserName' in code, but I do not know the others. I've tried looking at the log file, scesrv.log after I run the code for any information, but I couldn't find anything helpful. I've also tried looking at the official Microsoft Docs website for Secedit.exe, but I found nothing. I've tried replacing the 'DontDisplayLastUserName' value with something random in hopes that it would generate a helpful error message, but it ran fine without error and I am unsure why. This is concerning as it makes bug testing more difficult.

Specifically, I need to know the values for all 'Network security:' settings under Security Policy.
Any help is welcome, Thank-you.

Comment: This site isn't here to explain to you about security policies, what the items in the configuration do. We help you to fix a specific issue with your provided code. Please research this yourself and/or post your question to a more appropriate site. My advice is do not configure security settings especially when you don't know what they're doing or how it will affect your computer.

Comment: They are stored in the registry in an area where NO ONE has access (you can of course take ownership etc). They are stored in binary structures. After satisfying my curiosity once and deciding I can't do what I want safely, I left it well alone. Making a mistake may hose your system and you can't experiment without risking a mistake. Instead of doing your own stuff there is an API for LSA. This is how you access Windows' features, via the API. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secmgmt/management-portal